# Перестает работать запрос после добавление нового столбца

Tags: mysql

Всем добрый день!

Есть таблицы events(события),flats(квартиры)

Есть запрос вида

```
SELECT DISTINCT(flats.id), flats.street, flats.house, flats.apartment 
FROM flats 
RIGHT JOIN events 
ON flats.id = events.flats_id 
WHERE D1 <= events.reservation_time_start 
OR D2 >= events.reservation_time_end;
```

Данный запрос смотрит есть ли такое событие на квартиру(пересекающиеся интервалы)

Запрос замечательно работает до тех пор , пока в таблицу events не вносятся новые поля. Допустим внесли новое поле price - запрос перестал работать
Копирую структуру таблицы events, удаляю таблицу events, создаю новую таблицу events с уже новым полем price,запрос снова работает.
Может надо какие то обновления делать после добавление полей в таблицы?

Может я неправильно создаю таблицу

```
CREATE TABLE `gorod`.`events` (
 `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `flats_id` INT NULL,
 `clients_id` INT NULL,
 `real_time_start` TIMESTAMP NULL,
 `real_time_end` TIMESTAMP NULL,
 `reservation_time_start` TIMESTAMP NULL,
 `reservation_time_end` TIMESTAMP NULL,
 `client_comment` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
 `excursion` TINYINT(1) NULL,
 `interpreter` TINYINT(1) NULL,
 `personal_driver` TINYINT(1) NULL,
 `food` TINYINT(1) NULL,
 `transfer` TINYINT(1) NULL,
 `rent_car` TINYINT(1) NULL,
 `rent_laptop` TINYINT(1) NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`))
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8
COLLATE = utf8_general_ci;
```

Добавляю новые колонки так

```
ALTER table events Add column balance_due int;
```

Comment: А как конкретно проявляется то, что запрос не работает?

Comment: Например, в таблице events есть событие c 29 апреля по 30 апреля на объект 1
Запрос должен не выдавать этот объект, если я выбираю интервал с 29 апреля по 30 апреля. А запрос выдает этот объект

Comment: Не должно такого быть. Это какой-то баг.

Comment: Было бы здорово, если бы вы создали песочницу для публичного тестирования на sqlfiddle.com. Я уверен, что проблема не в каком-то дополнительном поле, а в том, что ваш запрос не о том, о чем вы пишете.

Answer (score 1):

Возможно, у вас есть таблицы с одинаковым именем в разных схемах:
 `gorod`.`events`

Попробуйте так:

```
ALTER table `gorod`.`events` Add column balance_due int;
```

Comment: Самое интересное что вылезла новая ошибка, при добавлении новой записи запрос тоже падает и неправильно выдает результат

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте заполнить поле после добавления какими-то значениями, чтобы оно не было `null`.

Answer (score 0):

Вы ошибаетесь:

1. Думаете, что DISTINCT умеет что-то делать с одним полем. Нет, он выбирает    уникальные сочетания всех полей из фразы SELECT!
2. Используете открытое объединение RIGHT JOIN, там где оно не нужно.
3. Пересечение временны́х интервалов задается не так. У вас условие с датами *не* выполняется только когда интервал внутри другого — что-то непонятное.

Пока эти проблемы не исправлены, вопрос не имеет смысла, IMHO. Ваш запрос просто нерабочий. В каких-то случаях результат попадает в ваши ожидания, хотя не обязан.